# How to save split training and testing data to file?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python and Keras to predict a continuous value from given data. I've already build my Neural Network model and got the results that I wanted. Here's what my code looks like:

```
X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)

X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)

print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_val.shape, Y_test.shape)
# Output: (693, 3) (148, 3) (149, 3) (693,) (148,) (149,)

#Building out model
model = Sequential([
Dense(9, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,)),
Dense(3, activation='relu'),
Dense(1, activation='linear'),
])

#Compiling model
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error',
         metrics=['mse'],
         optimizer='RMSprop')

#fit the model
 hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
     batch_size=100, epochs=20, verbose=1,
     validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

# evaluate model
model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
# Output: 149/149 [==============================] - 0s 42us/step
      #   [93.14884595422937, 171.0550879152029]
```

Now, after building the model, I would like to split the data and get accuracies for training and testing data separately. How can I do that?  Or extract the test and train data as a `.csv` file

Comment: Your question is confusing. You have _already_ split your data into training and testing sets, twice in fact, with `train_test_split`. If you want to check your accuracy on the training set, you can do it the same way you already have done on your testing set, with `model.evaluate()` but pass in the training data instead of the testing. Is that not what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry If it caused any confusion. To rephrase and make it in simple words, I just want to extract the test data and save it as a .csv file.

Comment: Aha, that's a completely different question. How is your data stored? Is it in numpy arrays? ([numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)) or pandas dataframes? ([df.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)) or some other data structure?

Comment: As a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Combine the `X_test` and `y_test` to a single dataframe and use `df.to_csv()`

Comment: What is the type of the variables which contain the data? Are they NumPy arrays?

Comment: They are as a Dataframe, but I've converted the data to an array using `df.values` after that normalizing the data using `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()`